# How are println and printf different in Jshell

Tags: java, printf, println

Why are println and printf displayed differently in Jshell??

I recently found out about JShell stuff and wanted to try a few things and I came across this.

[image: THIS is the 'this']

Why is output for println a plain output and output for printf all those stuff??

Answer (score 1):

[`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) returns a `PrintStream`, so jshell is showing you that returned value converted to a string (the stuff after `$1` and `$2`), which is shown that way because `PrintStream` doesn't override `toString` so it uses [the one from `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()).

As pointed out by Rogue in the comments, since `printf` doesn't print a newline unless instructed to, you see the return value on the same line as the printed value.

[`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) returns nothing, so you're only shown the printed value (and a newline).

Comment: Also probably worth noting for OP that printf will not print a newline automatically

Comment: So "println" returns void and "printf" returns PrintStream and since the returned value is to be stored somewhere those weird stuff are place where value of "printf" is stored? Did I get it?

Comment: `System.out.printf("...%n", ...);` for the needed newline at the end (similar to `\n` or print**ln**).

Comment: @user11246297 you don't *have* to store it somewhere, it's just that you're doing nothing with it so the shell is showing it. It's the same thing you get if you type `1+3`. You asked jshell to perform an operation and it's showing you the result. Then you can even use that result for further operations (try `$1 + 3` after the first operation) The part you were actually trying to print is "just" a side-effect.